# To get count of employee who are active and made plans using drive tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
select a.employee_made_plan,
    b.active
from employees e
left outer join (
    select count(fk_employeeid) employee_made_plan,
        fk_employeeid
    from v_employee emp
    inner join callplannermonthlevel c on emp.employeeid = c.fk_employeeid
    where month(c.planmonth) = 1
        and year(c.planmonth) = 2017
    ) a on e.employeeid = a.fk_employeeid
left outer join (
    select count(ev.isactive) active,
        employeeid
    from v_employee ev
    where ev.isactive = 1
    ) b on e.employeeid = b.employeeid
```

I want to get total count of active employee & those who had made plan in the current month, through, CallPlannerMonthLevel table.
The display should be like 23 & 12, meaning 23 are active & 12 made the plan in January.

### ActiveEmployee

23

### PlanMadeByEmployeeInCurrentMonth

12

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: An example of what the tables look like would certainly help.

Comment: you want to see what tables contain?

Comment: Not actual data, but some examples would help, yes

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output based on it along with logic explanation.

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi i am unable to give you the example as I cant access it out of office. :|

Comment: @GurV expected output will be ;

Active_Employees                 PlannedMadeByEmp
23                                          12

Comment: Please add it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this should do what you want by using `count(distinct))` for EmployeeIds of active employees, and a regular `count(c.[...])` to count plans.:

```
select 
    ActiveEmployee = count(distinct 
      case when e.IsActive =1 then e.EmployeeID else null end
      )
  , PlanMadeByEmployeeInCurrentMonth= count(c.Fk_EmployeeID)
  from v_Employee e
    left join CallPlannerMonthLevel C
      on e.EmployeeID = C.Fk_EmployeeID
     and dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, c.planmonth), 0) = '20170101'
    /* alternately, use current month like below: */ 
    -- = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() ), 0)
```

Comment: select 
(
select COUNT(IsActive) Active_Employees
from v_EmployeeHierarchyDetailWithID
where IsActive IS NOT NULL
) as 'Active Employees',

(select count(C.fk_CPM_EMP_EmployeeID) Plans_Emp 
from v_EmployeeHierarchyDetailWithID E
left outer join CallPlannerMonthLevel C
on E.EmployeeId= C.fk_CPM_EMP_EmployeeID
and MONTH(C.CPM_PlanMonth) = 1
and YEAR(C.CPM_PlanMonth) = 2017
and E.IsActive = 1
and E.Level6LevelId is not null
) as 'Plan of Employees'

Here..

Comment: @S.Quratulain right... Why use one query when you can use two?... A little backwards, but okay.